# Spliting string to array by constant number

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'v been trying to split string to array of components by number, but have no idea how to do it. I know that each components lenght is 9 except the last one. But there is no separation between them. Maybe anyone would know how could i make this split possible?

string : E44000000R33000444V33441
And i'd like to get array with: E44000000 R33000444 V33441

in past I'v used this method, but i guess there should be a way to separate by constant number. Any ideas

```
NSArray *myWords = [message componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

Comment: Check my answer... and comment if it works!!!

Comment: i have changed my answer a little, please check it.

Comment: last edit, i varified it, you can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated the NSString, and i didn't found any function like that. But you can create a category of NSString and put this function in that category and you can use as a NSString instance method.

```
- (NSArray *) componentSaparetedByLength:(NSUInteger) length{
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
        NSString *subString = nil;
        while (range.location + range.length <= self.length) {
            subString = [self substringWithRange:range];
            [array addObject:subString];
            //Edit
            range.location = range.length + range.location;
            //Edit
            range.length = length;
        }

        if(range.location<self.length){
            subString = [self substringFromIndex:range.location];
            [array addObject:subString];
        }
        return array;
}
```

Comment: Sunil, would it be possible to get a modified version of your answer than only splits the strings on a space? (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25616525/941076).  Basically want what you have, but don't want it to split words when it splits the string.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code.

```
NSString *stringTest = @"E44000000R33000444V33441323";
NSMutableArray *arrayTest = [NSMutableArray array];
while([stringTest length] > 8) {
    [arrayTest addObject:[NSString stringWithString:[stringTest substringToIndex:9]]];
    stringTest = [stringTest substringFromIndex:9];
}
NSLog(@"arrayTest - %@", arrayTest);
```

Comment: This function is creating unnecessarily lots of string object.

Comment: Yes, it is. :-( I will follow your answer. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one..

```
NSString *mainString=@"E44000000R33000444V";
NSMutableArray *brokenString=[NSMutableArray new];

int start=0;
for (; start<mainString.length-9; start+=9) {
     [brokenString addObject:[mainString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, 9)]];
}
[brokenString addObject:[mainString substringFromIndex:start]];
NSLog(@"->%@",brokenString);
```

Output is :

```
->(
    E44000000,
    R33000444,
    V
)
```

Comment: Haha, any code will look similar for string manipulation? If I say u have copied same code from Param with little bit of changes then??

Comment: It crashes if one of the components is less than lenght of 9. And as writen in question bottom there is possibility that lenght of last component may be less than 9,

Comment: **I know that each components lenght is 9.** Is What you mentioned :(

Comment: Explain clearly... can your string be XA1S22D333FaaE44000000R33000444V33441323?? so that I can give you a general solution..

Comment: String: (1leter E|R|V) + 8 numbers. last component (1leter V) + 8 or less numbers. I do not need that last component, so it could be just thrown away. Is this definition clear enough of that my string may be :)?

Comment: E42001000E42002000R16901017R30100000E57900101E57900002E57900003V2039 here is the input. I get substringFromRange exception, out of bounds.

Comment: For this...my nslog is  ->(
    E42001000,
    E42002000,
    R16901017,
    R30100000,
    E57900101,
    E57900002,
    E57900003,
    V2039
)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21057/discussion-between-datenshi-and-anoop-vaidya)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the substring upto the characters which you want in a loop(string length) & pass the next index for getting the next substring. After getting each substring you can add it to the array.
Used `SubstringToIndex` & `SubstringFromIndex` functions to get the substring.

Answer (score 0):

Also not an requirement here, I want to propose a solution that is capable of handling characters from more sophisticated script systems, like [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF), base characters plus [combining marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), [Hangul jamo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul), and [Indic consonant clusters](http://rishida.net/scripts/indic-overview/#consonantclusters).

```
@interface NSString (Split)
-(NSArray *)arrayBySplittingWithMaximumSize:(NSUInteger)size
                                     options:(NSStringEnumerationOptions) option;
@end

@implementation NSString (Split)

-(NSArray *)arrayBySplittingWithMaximumSize:(NSUInteger)size
                                     options:(NSStringEnumerationOptions) option
{
    NSMutableArray *letterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])
                                options:(option)
                             usingBlock:^(NSString *substring,
                                          NSRange substringRange,
                                          NSRange enclosingRange,
                                          BOOL *stop) {
                                 [letterArray addObject:substring];
                             }];


    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [letterArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (idx%size == 0) {
            [array addObject: [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:size]];
        }
        NSMutableString *string = [array objectAtIndex:[array count]-1];
        [string appendString:obj];

    }];

    return array;
}

@end
```

usage

```
NSArray *array = [@"E44000000R33000444V33441" arraysBySplittingWithMaximumSize:9 
                                                                       options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences];
```

results in:

```
(
    E44000000,
    R33000444,
    V33441
)
```